# Special Function, Series Expansion, or Simpler Form of a Certain Infinite Product?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, special-functions

$\prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(1+a (c+n)^b\right)$   where a > 0, b < -1, and c >= 0

Is there a special function, series expansion, or other simpler (or maybe just interesting) representation of this infinite product ?

Answer (score 2):

This is but a partial answer.

If $c$ is integer, then you can add a few terms to reduce the problem to
$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+an^b)$. If in addition $b$ is integer, then you can write
$$(1+an^b) = \prod_{\xi^b=-a}(1+(-\frac \xi n))$$
and reduce to a finite product of inverses of $\Gamma$ functions and exponentials,
using the product formula for $\Gamma$ (at complex values of the parameter).

I don't know what to make of the general case, but there are more knowledgeable people here.